# Thumbnail of the latest posts page

Tags: loop, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, options

I have a page "Blog" and it's set to display latest posts. This page itself has a thumbnail, and I want it to be displayed in header. 
Every other page/post has same layout and thumbnail shows in header just fine. 
And I managed to make it somehow work on "Blog" page also.

Here is my code:

```
<?php global $post;

if ( is_home() ) {
    $currentpageid = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
} else {
    $currentpageid = $post->ID;
}
$page_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($currentpageid), 'full' ); ?>

<header <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> style="background-image: url(<?php echo $page_thumb['0'];?>)"<?php }?>></header>
```

Now the strange thing is that the "Blog" page's thumbnail shows up in header only if latest post in the loop also has a thumbnail. What could be the reason?

***EDIT***

well, `$currentpageid = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );` actually returns a correct page id in this case, I can echo it anywehere. But when i try to pass it to any function - it doesn't work

```
$page_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($currentpageid), 'full' );
```

Comment: A quick test indicated that this should work. I can only assume that I have duplicated your setup correctly. Please explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: @s_ha_dum thanks for stopping by. well, it does work ONLY if the newest post in the loop (which is displayed right after the header) has a featured thumbnail image. In this case all thumbnails show up correctly. But if I delete a thumbnail for the newest post in the loop, the thumbnail of the 'latest posts' page also disappears.

Comment: I don't see that behavior. The current post in the loop doesn't seem to matter. There is something happening that I am not duplicating.

Comment: @s_ha_dum humph, that's weird. I'm now clearing the rest of my markup piece by piece to find what could cause such behaviour.

Comment: anyway, good to know that this code if fine, thanks @s_ha_dum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how the thumbnail url should be called:

```
<header <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail($currentpageid) ) { ?> style="background-image: url(<?php echo $page_thumb['0'];?>)"<?php }?>></header>
```